# Knockout attr href output issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a control that allows a user to save some links. He can add a display value of the link (basically the text within the `<a>`) and the link itself (the `href` attribute).

The problem is, I can't know whether he's adding the protocol as well (the `http://` or `https://` part, which is usually a result of copy-pasting a link from a browser's URL address bar) or he's manually typing 'www....'.

Basically, if the user types the address manually (www..) it will get appended to the current domain - here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/ty4tLtkj/4/

This is avoided if the user appends the `http://` part in front of the link - example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ty4tLtkj/5/

Is there a way to make sure the link that was entered NEVER gets appended to the domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the string for http;

```
var out = $("#input").val();
if(!out.match(/^https?:\/\//i)) //User didn't type http(s)://
{
    out = "http://" + out; //So add http://
}
```

Now: "http://google.nl" will be the same but "www.google.nl" will be "http://www.google.nl"

To explain .match(/^https?:\/\//i), this is regex:

- ^ = begins with.
- http
- s? = s or no s.
- :\/\/ = ://
- i = case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
if (pathname.substring(0, 7) == "http://" || pathname.substring(0, 8) == "https://")
```

or

```
if (pathname.substring(0, 3) == "www")
```

Otherwise its not possible because links without `http(s)://` get automatically appended to the current url.